# swf address does not work when I go out of the flash application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am using swfAddress **2.4** for browser navigation and everything (back and forth button in the browser) works fine as long as I stay in my flash website, but when I use back button eventually to go out of the website and then use the forth button to come back , it just takes me to the home page of my website, instead of the last page I was in my website before I hit the back button. it looks like I loose the history of my pages as soon as I go out of my flash application.

how can I make the browser navigation with swfAddress works when I go out of my flash application and want to comeback to that? and still have the history of my pages

I am working with flash builder , and flex 4.1
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put a trace() statement inside the handler for the SWFAddressEvent CHANGE event. You want to trace the value of the deep link when you re-enter the flash site. It could be that this handler isn't firing when you re-enter the site.

```
private function handleSWFAddress():void
{
    var value:String = SWFAddress.getValue();
    trace("value " + value);

}
```

When you re-enter the site the whole flash swf file has to reload. Be sure that when the site initialises, it sets up the handler for the SWFAddress CHANGE event:

```
SWFAddress.onChange = handleSWFAddress;
```

A detailed example is here:
http://oreilly.com/flash/excerpts/seo-for-flash/using-swfaddress-flex.html